# error ./c.sh: line 24: [: too many arguments in shell program

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, command-line, command

I am trying to make a shell script to print the amount of time user was logged into the system but I encountered a `too many arguments error`.  I tried many methods from the internet but none worked. Can someone spot the mistake?

```
#!/bin/bash 

lt=`who | grep "jeevansai" | cut -c 35-39`
lh=`echo $lt | cut -c 1-2`
lm=`echo $lt | cut -c 4-5`
ld=`who | grep "jeevansai" | cut -c 32-34`

ch=`date +%H`
cm=`date +%M`
cd=`date +%d`

fun()
{
  if [ $cm -gt $lm ]
  then
  {
    sm=`expr $cm - $lm`
    sh=`expr $ch - $lh`
  }
  else
  {
    sm=`expr 60 - $lm - $cm`
    sh=`expr $ch - $lh - 1`
  }
  fi
  exit 1
}
if [ $ld -gt $cd ]
then
{
  if [ $ch -gt $lh ]
  then
  {
    fun
  }
  else
  {
    sh=`expr 24 - $lh + $ch`
    sm=`expr 60 - $lm + $cm`
  }
  fi
}
else
  fun
fi
echo "$sh hr $sm min"
```

Output of `bash -x c.sh`:

```
++ who
++ grep jeevansai
++ cut -c 35-39
+ lt='22:27
23:18'
++ echo 22:27 23:18
++ cut -c 1-2
+ lh=22
++ echo 22:27 23:18
++ cut -c 4-5
+ lm=27
++ who
++ grep jeevansai
++ cut -c 32-34
+ ld='31 
31 '
++ date +%H
+ ch=23
++ date +%M
+ cm=24
++ date +%d
+ cd=31
+ '[' 31 31 -gt 31 ']'
c.sh: line 24: [: too many arguments
+ fun
+ '[' 24 -gt 27 ']'
++ expr 60 - 27 - 24
+ sm=9
++ expr 23 - 22 - 1
+ sh=0
+ exit 1
```

Comment: Could you please post the output of `bash -x c.sh`?

Comment: `bash` != `c`.  You don't need all those `{` `}` in the `if` `then` `else` `fi` statements.  (Conversely the function body does need them).

Comment: output of bash -x c.sh is posted

Comment: Using Unix epoch (`+%s`) would be easier: `last=$(date +%s -d "$(who | grep jeevansai | head -1 | grep -o '....-..-.. ..:..')") && now=$(date +%s) && m=$(((now-last)/60)) && echo "$((m/60)) hr $((m%60)) min"`

Comment: but what is the reason for error

Comment: Note that `who` gives several lines of output, and more than one match the `grep "jeevansai"`.  Thus the `ld` variable ends up with the value `31\n31`.  This is then expanded by `if [ $ld -gt $cd ]` to `'[' 31 31 -gt 31 ']'` which is incorrect syntax.  You can see this in the output you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assuming that the output of `who | grep jeevansai` will be a single line, which is wrong.

```
++ who
++ grep jeevansai
++ cut -c 32-34
+ ld='31 
31 '
```

This is telling you that the command

```
ld=`who | grep "jeevansai" | cut -c 32-34`
```

set the variable `ld` to "`31 31`", rather than to a single number as you were expecting.  Later, you try to do math on it ...

```
if [ $ld -gt $cd ]
```

... expands to ...

```
if [ 31 31 -gt 31 ]
```

and that's too many arguments to `[`.

What you need to do is take the *minimum* of all the dates that come back from `who`.  Unfortunately, date arithmetic is not easy in shell (note that your program currently ignores the month field altogether).  I'd personally reach for Perl or Python instead.

**EDIT:** For anyone who might be wondering *why* `who` prints more than one line of output for a single user: on a modern Unix workstation (OSX included) *every shell window you have open* will usually get its own entry, because each shell window allocates a [pseudoterminal](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pty), and the [`utmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/utmp) database that `who` uses, counts each active terminal (pseudo- or otherwise) as its own login.  Similarly, `screen` and `tmux` will allocate one pseudoterminal for each pane.  You might also have a  utmp entry for the entire graphical session.  All this stuff was designed in the 1970s and hasn't been changed much since.  For example, here's what it looks like on my Mac when I have two shell windows open:

```
$ who
zwol     console  Aug 18 09:59 
zwol     ttys000  Aug 19 09:49 
zwol     ttys001  Aug 19 10:35
```

Comment: Of course that can be done easily in a shell script, the tools are `sort` and `head`.

Comment: @ott-- Did someone add date collation to `sort` while I wasn't looking?

Comment: `sort -g`. Check the man page.

Comment: @ott-- "General numeric sort" will not put "Aug" after "Jul"...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't recognize Aug or Jul in the assignment `ld='31\n31`.

Comment: @ott-- I am imagining how I would write the OP's program from scratch and make it *perfect*, rather than the minimal change required to make it work (in which context, you're right, `sort -n` and `head` will do the job).  `who` output contains timestamps like `Aug 18 09:59` and OP has carved that up into day, hour, minute using `cut`, but didn't even try to handle the month.  (I don't know what `who` does if you stay logged on across a year boundary.)